# In CKEDITOR How to find next item to current cursor positon?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

In **CKEDITOR** How to find next item to current cursor positon

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var b=EditorInstance.document.getSelection();
  var ranges = b.getRanges();
  //console.log(ranges[0]);
   console.log(ranges[0].getNextNode().$.nodeName);
```

it'll returned nextNode name after cursor positions.
if your cursor startoffset is 100 then getNextNode function provide u 101 position item.